# Remove whitespaces between words and collapse double whitespaces in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, text

I have the following text:

```
T h i s  i s  s o m e  t e x t .
```

What I need is the following:

```
This is some text.
```

The structure follows a regular pattern, so I'd assume there is a way to perform the necessary modifications using a shell command (can also be a script of some sort). I'm not that proficient in shell-tools, so I couldn't come up with something that works..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you storing this in a string? i.e. i/p a string or content of a file

Comment: @OP: [Can you check this demo](http://ideone.com/OsBMS2) and see if this is the right output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe 's/ (?! )//g' -- input.txt
```

- `(?!` is a "negative look-ahead assertion", which means the whole pattern means *a space not followed by a space*

Comment: If there are 2 spaces before DOT then it leaves one space in output.

Comment: @anubhava: Sure, 2 spaces are reduced to one, one space is removed.

Comment: Shouldn't both spaces be removed as per OP's output

Comment: @anubhava: There's only a single space before the dot.

Answer (score 3):

With sed you can do:

```
$ echo "$a"
T h i s  i s  s o m e  t e x t .

$ sed 's/\(.\) /\1/g' <<< "$a"
This is some text.
```

Comment: [See this demo](http://ideone.com/OsBMS2) as comments are pretty bad for entering string with multiple spaces.

Comment: @anubhava: I see, not sure what OP wants to happen if there as more than three consecutive spaces.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` or `perl` variants mentioned above are the straight-forward ways to do it.

Here is `awk` variant as an example.:

```
$ awk -F'[ ]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i=="") $i=" "; printf "%s", $i}}' <<< 'T h i s  i s  s o m e  t e x t .'
This is some text.

$ awk -F'[ ]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i=="") $i=" "}}1' OFS= <<< 'T h i s  i s  s o m e  t e x t .'
This is some text.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this gnu sed that is based on word boundaries:

```
s='T h i s  i s  s o m e  t e x t    .'

sed -E 's/\b( +\B| )//g' <<< "$s"
```

**Output:**

```
This is some text.
```